# A little Python life simulation game

Tags: python, python-3.x, game

This is one of many little python text based games that I have to share here!

This one is a life sim game, try to get as far as possible without reaching 0 thirst, you can replenish, of course. Try to get as many degrees as possible, and start making big bucks!

If you have any questions or feedback, please let me know!

```
import time
import sys
import random
#####
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.money = 0
###############################
        self.health = 100
        self.water = 100
        self.food = 100
###############################
        pass


p = Player("Player")




class emblem:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.emblem = 0
        pass

begemb = emblem("Begger Emblem")
apart = emblem("Apartment Key")
college = emblem("College emb")

admin = emblem("Admin Emblem")

class Job:

    def __init__(self, name, requirements, pay):
        self.name = name
        self.requirements = requirements
        self.pay = pay
        pass
beg = Job("Begging", 0, 10)
jojo = Job("Fast Food", 0, 100) #requires apartment emblem


class foo:

    def __init__(self, name, price, fill):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.fill = fill
        pass
dai = foo("Daily Set of Essentials", 30, 100)   ##decrease of 10 per day for


#upkeep



def stats():
    p.water -= 10
    p.food -= 10
    print("Food:")
    print p.food
    print("Water:")
    print p.water
    if p.water == 0:
        print("Game Over")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Money:")
        print p.money
        cycle()

def cycle():
    if apart.emblem == 1:
        print("1.) Store")
        print("2.) To The Day")
        print("3.) School")
        cyclea = input("")
        if cyclea == 1:
            store()
        elif cyclea == 2:
            job()
        elif cyclea == 3:
            school()
    else:
        print("1.) Store")
        print("2.) To The Day")
        cycle = input("")
        if cycle == 1:
            store()
        if cycle == 2:
            job()

def stores():
    store()

def store():
    print("1.) +100 Health, 100 Water, 100 Food. (30$)")
    print("2.) Apartment Key (300$)")
    print("3.) Back")
    store = input("")
    if store == 1:
        p.money -= 30
        p.health += 100
        p.water += 100
        p.food += 100
        print("+100 Health")
        print("+100 Water")
        print("+100 Food")
        stores()
    elif store == 2:
        apart.emblem += 1
        stores()
    elif store == 3:
        cycle()
    elif store == 887324:
        admin.emblem += 1
        stores()

def job():
    if college.emblem == 1:
        print("You are eligible for:")
        print("1.) Begging / Pay: 10")
        print("2.) Working in fast food restuarant / Pay: 100")
        print("3.) Working in office / Pay: 1000")
        print("4.) Working in institution / Pay: 3500")
        cme = input("")
        if cme == 1:
            p.money += 10
            stats()
        elif cme == 2:
            p.money += 100
            stats()
        elif cme == 3:
            p.money += 1000
            stats()
        elif cme == 4:
            p.money += 3500
            stats()


    elif high.emblem == 1:
        print("You are eligible for:")
        print("1.) Begging / Pay: 10")
        print("2.) Working in fast food restuarant / Pay: 100")
        print("3.) Working in office / Pay: 1000")
        highme = input("")
        if highme == 1:
            p.money += 10
            stats()
        elif highme == 2:
            p.money += 100
            stats()
        elif highme == 3:
            p.money += 1000
            stats()



    elif apart.emblem == 1:
        print("You are eligible for:")
        print ("1.) Begging / Pay: 10")
        print("2.) Working In Fast Food Restuarant / Pay: 100")
        job = input("")
        if job == 1:
            p.money += 10
            stats()
        if job == 2:
            p.money += 100
            stats()
    else:
        print("You are eligible for:")
        print("1.) Begging / Pay: 10")
        job1 = input("")
        if job1 == 1:
            p.money += 10
            stats()
high = emblem("High School Graduate")

def schools():
    school()

def school():
    if high.emblem == 1:
        print("1.) College / 5000")
        print("2.) Back")
        papi = input("")
        if papi == 1:
            college.emblem += 1
            schools()
        elif papi == 2:
            cycle()



    elif admin.emblem == 1:
        print("1.) Admin School / FREE")
        adme = input("")
        if adme == 1:
            high.emblem += 1
            cycle()
    else:
        print("1.) High School / 1000")
        print("2.) Back")
        schoolme = input("")
        if schoolme == 1:
            p.money -= 1000
            high.emblem += 1
            schools()
        elif schoolme == 2:
            cycle()


def day():
    print("")














stats()
```

Comment: You have posted four questions recently, all of which are actually quite similar to each other in style, and have similar issues. Please wait for feedback on existing questions before posting more questions.

Answer (score 2):

I am running this on Python 3.7.2, but I think my answer will work.

on line 65, or

> ```
> print p.food
> ```

You are missing parentheses around `p.food`. So you should change it to this:

```
print(p.food)
```

This also happens on line 67 and 73.

When you use input, the input function returns a string. However, in your code, you do not use quotes around your results, like this:

```
print("1.) +100 Health, 100 Water, 100 Food. (30$)")
print("2.) Apartment Key (300$)")
print("3.) Back")
store = input("")
if store == 1:
    p.money -= 30
    p.health += 100
    p.water += 100
    p.food += 100
    print("+100 Health")
    print("+100 Water")
    print("+100 Food")
    stores()
elif store == 2:
    apart.emblem += 1
    stores()
elif store == 3:
    cycle()
elif store == 887324:
    admin.emblem += 1
    stores()
```

On the `if` statements in your code, you use integers rather than strings. Add quotes around them, or change the input to integers. Like this:

```
if store == 1:
```

or

```
store = int(input(""))
```